# How to start Mongoose connection when the database is outside of the server folder?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to start my connection to Mongoose when the database folder is outside of the server folder (The server folder being the one that contains my `express` app).

Here is my structure

```
Server
   app.js

Database
  index.js
  schemas
     userSchema.js
```

In my `index.js` folder I have:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var credentials = require('../config/credentials');


var userModel = require('./schemas/user');

//Connections
var developmentDb = credentials.testConnection;


var database;

//If in development
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  //set database to development one
  database = developmentDb;
}



//Connect to the database
mongoose.connect(database);

//Get an instance of the connection to our database
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Connection error:'));

db.once('open', function () {
  console.log('Database connection successfully opened at ' + database);
});


exports.user = userModel;
```

But I never see the `database connection successfully opened` message upon starting my node app...

Comment: Are you `require`ing this `index.js` file anywhere in your application?

Comment: Is the method `mongoose.connect(database)` getting the right parameters? Log the `database` variable and check this...

Comment: do you get anything fired if you listen for `'connected'` instead of `'open'`?

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny, it does not export a function, only a model, so what would `require` do?

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny, you are right, I did have to `require` that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with the structure of your project, you could split it into folders in any way you want.

The actual problem is that you're not `require`ing your `Database/index.js` in your application:

```
require('../Database');
```

And since you're not `require`ing it, `node.js` is not executing it.

Comment: yes. Although it is `Database/index.js` you are right.

Comment: @Startec `'../Database'` is a shortcut for `'../Database/index.js'`. ;)

Comment: @Startec see [Folders as Modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules) for more info about `requir`ing directories.

Comment: Right right, I was just referring to how you said `index.coffee` ;)